# android Gridview reloading array

Tags: android, arrays, gridview

I am working on GridView for the first time and came across the following issue. I am referring this tutorial http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html
well the icons and text are displayed exactly in the sequence as it is in array. as shown in the following screenshot
1st screenshot:[image: image from the tutorial link]

but when i increase the columns width and height so that not all the data is seen at once(i.e i need to scroll down to see the data at the end.i guess the following screenshots might help.

2nd screenshot: [image]

3rd screenshot this are the remaining contents that can be viewed after scrolling down:[image]

If you compare the actual array of text i.e "String[] web" from the link or the 1st screenshot. Till stumbleUpon it is displaying the correct sequence of array but after that 'github' ,'google' and 'facebook' is being displayed instead of  "SoundCloud","Reddit", "Blogger".

Now my question is: why is this happening? does the adapter only loads the contents that are visible and it reloads the contents once other part is made visible?
may i know what is the solution for this? or what is the right approach to use gridview?

If you are not able to understand my doubts.Please feel free to ask.Thank you in advance.

Comment: posting the adapter code might help me to solve your problem.

Comment: you can find it in the tutorial link http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html
CustomGrid.java is the adapter code in it.

Comment: read the behaviour of adapter and gridview you will come to know about it:)

Comment: I have read the examples mentioned at developers.com. It says that the getView() method in adapter creates a new View for each data passed.My question is why is it behaving weirdly when the entire view becomes bigger to fit in the screen.i.e scrolling comes in picture?

Comment: see there is something called recycling of views

 if (convertView == null)  
this statement checks where a view is null. if the view is created(when not null) the update the essential like in your case text and image(which you had missed).

Comment: hey i understood this.. but my question is when the view was suppose null  for the first time when view was created.. at that time only why it isnt loading the array completely? the first few elements its loading properly.. there is no issue with the elements at the start..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**put this code in else condition it will work**

```
         TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        textView.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
```

***so whats happening is when the view is getting reused, you are not setting the data(ie is image and the text)***

Comment: hey thanks its working.. can you please explain why it isnt loading all the data the first time?what is the exact behaviour? like when i scroll up does it starts reloading array again?

Comment: i have even tried the same code in other application and there the array was getting loaded in the sequence 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-0-7.. where the last to elements where not in view unless i scroll up.. what is the cause of this behaviour exactly?